# Focus using FormControlName as selector

Tags: angular

I have two controls a and b, on blur of b, I have written an event which should check whether a is not empty.

My form is a reactive form, so I haven`t added id, is it possible to focus with formcontrolname rather than using id or class.

```
  public nullCardNum;
    isCardNumNull(): { [key: string]: boolean } {
        let cardNumLength = this.paymentForm.controls["cardNumber"].value.length;
        if (cardNumLength == 0) {
            this.nullCardNum = true;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my function..

Comment: Have you read how to write validators for reactive forms ? https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions

Comment: yes I have studied, can u help on how to do above scenario..

Answer (score 0):

[Try Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/focus-using-formcontrolname-as-selector)

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="paymentForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="a" placeholder="control a">
    <input type="text" (blur)="checkonBlur($event)" formControlName="b" placeholder="control b">

</form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormControlDirective, FormControlName, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


const originFormControlNgOnChanges = FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges = function () {
  this.form.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return originFormControlNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
};

const originFormControlNameNgOnChanges = FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges = function () {
  const result = originFormControlNameNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
  this.control.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return result;
};



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  el: ElementRef
  name = 'Angular 6';
  paymentForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      a: null,
      b: ''
    })
  }

  checkonBlur(event) {
    console.log(this.paymentForm.get('a').value)
    if (this.paymentForm.get('a').value === null || this.paymentForm.get('a').value == '') {
      (<any>this.paymentForm.get('a')).nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have taken scenario of control 'a' is null, you can add any condition on it. I suggest to use reactive form validation as well

Comment: condition is one thing and result is other.

Comment: I`m getting error Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined --getting this error

Comment: isCardNumNull(event): { [key: string]: boolean } {
        let cardNumLength = this.paymentForm.controls["cardNumber"].value.length;
        if (cardNumLength == 0) {
            this.nullCardNum = true;
            document.getElementById("cardNumberid").focus();
            (<any>this.paymentForm.get('cardNumber')).nativeElement.focus();
            //let element = document.querySelector("input[formControlName='cardNumber']");
            //element.focus();
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: have you added 'cardNumber' in controls??

Comment: isCardNumNull() {
    let cardNum = this.paymentForm.get('cardNumber').value;
    if (cardNum == null || cardNum == '') {
      (<any>this.paymentForm.get('cardNumber')).nativeElement.focus();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```sh
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef
} from "@angular/core";


constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {}


scrollTo(el: Element) {
    if (el) {
      el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }

const invalidElements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(
          ".ng-invalid"
        );

        if (invalidElements.length > 0) {
          this.scrollTo(invalidElements[1]); // invalidElements[0] is the total form element
        }
      }
```